# get_template_directory_uri() in Jquery and CSS

Tags: wordpress, codex

I am trying to use get_template_directory_uri() to load images to a jquery.backstretch.js file and to my styles.css as well. So far, I added my images directly in the theme folder in a folder named "img" and I have used this for my HTML:

```
 <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logoyellow.png" class="hidden-xs" alt="logo" />
```

That worked fine!

But I did the following in a jquery file (jquery.backtretch.js):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#home-section").backstretch("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/background-image2.jpg");
   });
```

But no cigar :( I also wold like to know how to load it in my CSS. Something like this:

```
  #milestones-section {
      background: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/hbg.jpg') center center;
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JS files aren't parsed by PHP, so you won't get access to functions like `get_template_directory_uri()`.

#### The Quick and Dirty Way

You can make that available to Javascript by putting something like this in the `<head>` of each page:

```
<script>
    theme_directory = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>";
</script>
```

#### The Right Way

You should probably load js in the correct Wordpress manner, using `wp_register_script()` and/or `wp_enqueue_script()`.  If you do that, you can use the Wordpress function `wp_localize_script()` and make whatever information you like available to that script.

More information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

#### CSS

You CSS files should already be in the theme directory, so you can use relative paths for that.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Herbert works well
but if anybody need it to write this to innerHTML, for Example on a button:

1.) insert into example.php file:

```
<?php 
function loadDirectory() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var theme_directory = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>";
</script> 
<?php } 
add_action('wp_head', 'loadDirectory'); ?>
```

2.) in script.js file:

```
document.getElementById('exampleButton').innerHTML = '<img src="' + theme_directory + '/svg/icons/cursor.svg" width="32" height="32" title="">Example';
```

Maybe it helps